# How to subForm a subForm with ZendX_Jquery TabContainer/TabPane?

Tags: php, jquery, zend-form, zendx, zend-form-sub-form

I try to get Zend_From working with nested jquery tabs.
I know how to do it with plain HTML/jQuery, and i also have a single tab row working with decorators and so on. (see http://i56.tinypic.com/9zt5qf.jpg for an example)

Has anyone managed to subForm a subForm with ZendX_Jquery TabContainer/TabPane ?

As soon as i add the subForm to the subForm, the form is not rendered anymore (the only "element" is the submit button, which is outside any subform).

---

EDIT:

After further playing around with it, the problem is with the decorators. 
the mainform is a tabcontainer, the subform in it is a tabpane, so a subform in a subform would need to be both, tabcontainer for its own subforms, and tabpane for the mainform.

TIA
Rufinus

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to divide a subForm into several subForms or have subForms containing other subForms?

Comment: the second i guess. but it seems both are pretty similar. which normaly is not a problem. as stated in the zend_form advanced document (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.advanced.html)  "Sub forms may be nested arbitrarily deep"

Comment: the problem is with the decorators. the mainform is a tabcontainer, the subform in it is a tabpane, so a subform in a subform would need to be both, tabcontainer for its own subforms, and tabpane for the mainform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Initialize nested tab with a function and call it onLoad , `<body onLoad="">`
2. try to call them in a linear way use [headjs](http://headjs.com/) ,
   i didn't used or managed to use like u but sort of same situation and be sure ZendX_Jquery is using same version as nested tabs do

Comment: this has nothing do to with jquery itself actually. more with setup the subforms and decorators of the zendx_jquery_form_view_helpers tabcontainer and tabpane to be precise

Comment: @Rufinus i did set 100 bounty again , cause my answer didn't helped at least for you and i've got 50 reps for nothing

Comment: thanks @synxmax very nice of you. The half bounty got autoarwarded couse you have got more then 2 upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

@Rufinus

You seem to have 3 tiers of subforms. I have used view scripts from my main form's setDecorators() method. Then in the view script I have used the viewHelper which returns form objects. This is added to the tabcontainer's pane and the tabcontainer is rendered.

This is well rendered. However, the problem is populating the elements in the innermost subform. It would be great to share a little on how you designed the 3 tiers. Thanks.